# Do Visual Studio references get cached somehow?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

- I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition.
- My development environment is a VM that I run in Microsoft Virtual PC 6.0.156.0
- For reasons better discussed outside of this question, I have the source code on a network share.  In addition, once a build is complete.  All references (just the release dll's and pdb's) are placed in an "Assemblies" folder on this network share.  Therefore, a project, any time I want to add a reference, has a reference added by navigating to this Assemblies folder.  I'm not directly linking in other projects.

This is the baffling see that I see:

I made a brand new dll on May 1st and placed it in my Assemblies folder.  At that time, I also opened up an existing project, and added this new DLL as a reference.

Today, I had to make a change to that DLL.  I make the change, build, and place the new DLL and PDB, dated 5/3, in the Assemblies folder.

I open up this existing project, delete my bin/obj folders, clean the solution, rebuild the solution - and when I look in this project's bin folder, it has the 5/1 dll and the 5/3 pdb.  That's right, it has the May 1st DLL.  The only place that 5/1 dll existed was in this Assemblies folder, as it's not on any folder in my VM at all.  This 5/1 dll was replaced with the 5/3 dll.  How is it not recompiling with the new DLL?

For ha-ha's, I went to the Assemblies folder and removed it.  Now it's gone.  My existing project shouldn't even have the ability to link this DLL at all.  None, whatsoever.  I delete bin/obj folders, clean, rebuild.  It compiles successfully.  I look in the bin folder and there's a 5/1 dll.

Where is it getting this DLL? It doesn't exist in any directory on any folder in my VM or in the Assembilies folder on this network share any more.  Heck, the 5/3 dll isn't there either.  There's no dll.  ANYWHERE!!!  Yet, my project is able to successfully recompile with an older non-existing DLL.  Something, somewhere is caching this somehow.  I'm completely stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use source control in a team? Blame your coworker.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like yes, even I had the exact same problem. On searching for the Dll in this location
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\' I found my dll under a folder which had the name same of my project name(within somany other folders with weird names).

Try deleting your dll where ever its present inside Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework. That might help.